# Highlighting trailing whitespace in emacs without changing character

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I am trying to get emacs to highlight trailing-spaces. I have tried using [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace), and also tried setting `show-trailing-whitespace` variable to true, but in each case it changes the representation of newline and space characters to `$` and `·` characters, as shown in this [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMPaK.png).

Ideally I would like to just see the trailing whitespace highlighted in red without any such characters.

Disclaimer: I'm new to emacs, so this may well be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value of the `whitespace-style` variable to

```
(face trailing)
```

You might need to restart whitespace-mode for the changes to take effect.

To set a variable, use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`set-variable`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 33):

I don't use any library.  I just set `show-trailing-whitespace` to `t` and any trailing white space is shown in red. The representation of newline and space characters is NOT changed.

Actually, my `".emacs"` file contains this simple line:

```
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
```

In case you don't want to edit your `".emacs"` file, you may try:

- `C-h v show-trailing-whitespace RET` then click the `customize` link
- (or just `M-x customize-variable RET show-trailing-whitespace RET`)
- Click the `toggle` button to set it to `on (non-nil)`
- Click the menu button `State` > `Set for Current Session`
- Click the menu button `State` > `Save for Future Sessions`

[EDIT] (thanks to **Francesco Frassinelli** for his comment)

With `setq-default`, the value is changed for every mode.

If you want to disable it for some mode (like `term-mode` for example), you have to:

- find the mode name of the current buffer. Usually you can get it from within the buffer with `M-x describe-mode RET` (shortcut `C-h m` or `<f1> m`).
- find the entry "hook" for this mode. Usually, it's the mode name with the suffix `-hook`. You can find it by searching "hook" in the buffer describing the mode. For example, you may read:

  `Entry to this mode runs the hooks on ‘term-mode-hook’`
- add the following to your `".emacs"` file:

  `(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))`
- or you may try:

  - `M-x customize-variable RET term-mode-hook RET`
  - Click the `INS` button
  - Paste `(lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil))`
  - Click the menu button `State` > `Set for Current Session`
  - Click the menu button `State` > `Save for Future Sessions`

Note that `show-trailing-whitespace` automatically becomes buffer-local when set with `setq`.

Comment: Works great for me! And thanks for the detailed instructions. For some reason, the other answer's `whitespace-style`'s `(face trailing)` setting did not highlight the trailing whitespace, so I'm glad we have this solution as well.

Comment: It seems to mess around with term: red block everywhere :-)

Comment: You're right! Maybe "term" should be considered as an exception. I added explanations on how to disable it for some mode. HTH

Comment: This seems to also show trailing whitespaces to `counsel`'s things in the minibuffer. Any idea how to fix this? Adding a hook for `counsel-mode` to set `show-trailing-whitespace` to nil doesn't seem to do anything: https://imgur.com/a/GvFEaT0.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is to use library [**`highlight-chars.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el) (description: [Highlight library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary)).

Command **`hc-toggle-highlight-trailing-whitespace`** does what you request.

You can also turn on such highlighting automatically, either everywhere or in a given buffer or for a given mode.